# Custom Component Not working as expected

Tags: visualforce, visualforce-component, style

I am using an example of custom component from - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_comp_cust_elements_attributes.htm

Here is my custom Component:

```
<apex:component>


    <!-- Attribute Definitions -->
    <apex:attribute name="myValue" description="This is the value for the component."
                    type="String" required="true"/>
    <apex:attribute name="borderColor" description="This is color for the border."
                    type="String" required="true"/>

    <!-- Component Definition -->
    <h1 style="border:{!borderColor};">
        <apex:outputText value="{!myValue}"/> 
    </h1>

</apex:component>
```

My VF page has:

```
<apex:page >

<c:recorddisplay myValue="My value" borderColor="red"/>

</apex:page>
```

When I check my VF page I do not get the Red border color or any where as "Red" color. I also tried below code in my component, but I do not see any background color in my page. What is wrong with this example? -

```
<h1 style="bgcolor:{!borderColor};">
        <apex:outputText value="{!myValue}"/> 
    </h1>
```

Comment: For the `border` property, you would usually specify (dimensions?) e.g. `border: 1px solid red` .. And `background-color` over `bgcolor`... At least Chrome doesn't seem to like `bgcolor`

Comment: That makes sense. The example in salesforce document looks wrong. This code in VF page worked- <c:recorddisplay myValue="My value" borderColor="1px solid red"/>

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately. Your usage of the `attribute` component is correct just css issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Documentation is not entirely correct.

the border property should be as follows:

```
border: width style color
```

So it would be:

```
style="border: 1px solid {!borderColor}"
```

although this would work as well

```
style="border: solid {!borderColor}"
```

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_border.asp

Comment: Your right! The document is not entirely correct.